# Is adhering to one assert per test foolish consistency in this case?

Tags: unit-testing, code-quality

I have a class that I'm testing. The class has a function: `apply(List<IRule> rules, List<ITarget> targets);`

In one test I want to ensure that each target has been passed to one rule, a la:

```
rule1.AssertWasCalled(fnord => fnord.Test(target1));
rule1.AssertWasCalled(fnord => fnord.Test(target2));
rule1.AssertWasCalled(fnord => fnord.Test(target3));
```

It seems to me that limiting myself to a single assertion statement would be quite the [hobgoblin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Reliance). Am I correct in this assumption, or is there some other way that I could assert that each target had, in fact, been tested?

Comment: I can see the fnords!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The three asserts are in essence one test. You are testing behaviour of a method on a collection, to make sure that each item has been a parameter for a specific call (i.e. that each item has been processed properly).

Setting the data up three times and in three different methods is wasteful and less readable than the alternative of having several asserts.

The single assert "rule" is more about making asserts of different types in the same methods (essentially testing different things), which doesn't really apply in this case, where you are testing for a single behaviour.

Comment: Indeed : the rule is more one *logical* assert per Unit Test. You could group those into one higher level assert that you could reuse in different tests.

Answer (score 5):

It's my belief that this one assert per test rule exists to keep your tests focused on one issue.  If you test 20 things in one test, it's really hard to tell what your coverage is.  You know it's causing a problem when you can't name the test method without the word **and** in it.  For example, if your test method would be more accurately named as `testFooIsTrueAndDbExistsAndBarIsNullAndAnExceptionDoesntOccur()`, you're probably testing too much in one test.

In your case, I think it's probably ok to assert three times.  If you want to make your code more readable, you could extract those three asserts into a method named `assertWasCalledOnTargets(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular example, you can get away with "one" assert statement if you do something like:

```
foreach target in targets
{
     rule1.AssertWasCalled(fnord => fnord.Test(target))
}
```

It's what I do to avoid feeling guilty about having multiple asserts in one test.

Comment: I've done this before. Not a bad way to go. It's easy to read, and you can understand the nature of what its doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this one, too.

The purist (in me) insists on one assert per test so I'll know **exactly** where things blew up.

And then I find myself cutting / pasting a lot of the same, redundant test setup code.  After the third or fourth layer of this, you start to say "Oy! Enough!"

My compromise has been to find the aspects that "never" break.  And I'll layer those pieces together and then add in *one* new element that could break.  Just to be clear, layering multiple volatile areas in one test would be a violation of this compromise.

Comment: You should check out `Assume`. I just learned about it today.

Answer (score 1):

If the setup code for `target1` is different from the setup code for `target2`, this type of corner-cutting tends to eventually lead overly long test initialization code.  This in turn is either a mess or ends up being refactored and re-used.  If your tests are complex enough to justify refactoring them, your test is probably testing more than one thing.

If the setup code for each target is essentially the same, splitting your test into multiple individual tests is probably overkill.

If `target1` and `target2` are different implementations of the same interface, you should instead be adding a unit test to the interface (and allowing your test framework to generate a test for every implementation of that interface).